# Drag drop image & upload it on multiple folder

Tags: javascript, php, image

Now I am performing an image upload operation by dragging the image on the field and I successfully uploaded it to the destination. Now I need to upload the same image on the multiple folders while dragging the image to the field, the image should be inserted in multiple folders. The problem arises when I try to upload the same image on multiple folder, the image getting inserted on first folder and not in others. I have attached the code below.

```
function uploadimage() {
    $headerimage=array();
    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        $headerimage[0] = 'uploadimages/post_ads'."/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
        echo move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$headerimage[0]);
        $headerimage[1] = 'uploadimages/latestimages'."/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
        echo move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$headerimage[1]);
        $headerimage[2] = 'uploadimages/listimages'."/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
        echo move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$headerimage[2]);
        $headerimage[3]  = 'uploadimages/photoimages'."/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
        //$headerpath = 'uploadimages/photoimages'."/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
        echo move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$headerimage[3]);
        $headerimage[4]  = 'uploadimages/slideimages'."/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
        //$headerpath = 'uploadimages/slideimages'."/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
        echo move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$headerimage[4]);
        print_r($headerimage);
        $_SESSION['upload_images'][]=$headerimage;
    }
}
```

In the `post_ads` folder the image is inserted but in other folders it isn't. Can any of you suggest me a possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move_uploaded_file will move the file, and not copy it -- which means it'll work only once.

If you are using copy, there shouldn't be any limit at all on the number of times you can copy : the temporay file created by the upload will only be destroyed at the end of the execution of your script (unless you move/delete it before, of course)

Still, maybe a solution would be to use move_uploaded_file first, and, then, copy ? 
A bit like that, I suppose :

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$headerimage[1])) {
    copy($headerimage[1], $headerimage[2]);
    copy($headerimage[1], $headerimage[3]);
    copy($headerimage[1], $headerimage[4]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some good php libraries for handling uploads. i`m using http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm it simplifies your job. you can upload files to multiple folders then like:

```
include('class.upload.php');
//--------------------------------------
$upload_handler = new Upload($_FILES['file']); 
if ($upload_handler->uploaded)
{
$new name = time().rand(10000,99999);
//----------------------------------------
$upload_handler->image_convert = 'jpg';
$upload_handler->jpeg_quality = 70;
$upload_handler->image_background_color = '#FFFFFF';
$upload_handler->image_resize = true;
$upload_handler->file_new_name_body = $new name;
$upload_handler->image_ratio_fill = true;
$upload_handler->image_ratio_no_zoom_in = true;
$upload_handler->image_x = 900;
$upload_handler->image_y = 700;
$upload_handler->Process('folder_path_1');
//-----------------------------------------
$upload_handler->image_convert = 'jpg';
$upload_handler->jpeg_quality = 70;
$upload_handler->image_background_color = '#FFFFFF';
$upload_handler->image_resize = true;
$upload_handler->file_new_name_body = $new name;
$upload_handler->image_ratio_fill = true;
$upload_handler->image_ratio_no_zoom_in = true;
$upload_handler->image_x = 150;
$upload_handler->image_y = 150;
$upload_handler->Process('folder_path_2');
//-----------------------------------------     

}
```

So you can resize, resample and so on and then you call Process for the different folders how many times you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestion guys. I have found the exact and simple way for it.I have attached the code below

```
function uploadimage()

{

if (!empty($_FILES)) {



        $headerimage= 'uploadimages/featuredimages'."/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
        $headerimage1= 'uploadimages/latestimages'."/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
        $headerimage2 = 'uploadimages/listimages'."/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
        $headerimage3  = 'uploadimages/photoimages'."/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
        $headerimage4  = 'uploadimages/slideimages'."/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
        $headerimage5  = 'uploadimages/galleryimages'."/".$_FILES['file']['name'];


          move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$headerimage);
          copy($headerimage,  $headerimage1 );
          copy($headerimage1,  $headerimage2 );
          copy($headerimage1, $headerimage3 );
          copy($headerimage1,$headerimage4 );
          copy($headerimage1,$headerimage5 );



    $_SESSION['upload_images'][]=$headerimage1;

}
}
```